# How to send lots of POST requests QUICKLY

Tags: c++, multithreading, perl, delphi, post

I'm planning to develop a program for our university research that has to send lots of post requests to different urls. It must work as quick as possible (we should process about 100kk urls). What language shoud i use (currently i'm writing in c++, delphi and perl a bit)?

Also, I've heard that it's possible to write an multithreaded app in perl using prefork that can process about 20-30k per minute. Is it true?

// Sorry for my bad english, but it seems to be the only place where i can get the right answer

Andrew

Comment: You could probably just hack the apache ab code to do the trick for you. Or you could just run multiple ab's simultaneously. This is the tools man page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: Do you mean 100M urls or 100kk was just a typo ?

Comment: You may use [RTC SDK](http://www.realthinclient.com/) to develop an App ISAPI extension on a ISAPI-capable Web Server to achieve that.

Comment: @menjaraz yes, 100 millions. Thanks too!

Comment: @user1239398 A friendly reminder that you should *accept* an answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 15):

The 20-30k per minute is completely arbitrary. If you run this on an 8-core machine with a beefy network connection you could probably surpass that.

However, I don't think your choice of programming language / library is going to matter much here. Instead, you're going to run into the number of concurrent TCP connections allowed by the machine, and also the bandwidth of the link itself.

Comment: +1 surely, this is going to be I/O limited on most networks.  Lots of threads to run lots of DNS lookups, (notoriously async-unfriendly), and send lots of POSTs seems like a good plan.

Answer (score 5):

[Webserver Stress Tool](http://www.paessler.com/webstress) claims capable of simulating the HTTP requests generated by **up to 10.000 simultaneous users** and has an entry in [Torry's site](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=1524): Presumably it's written in Delphi or C++ Builder.

**My suggestion:**

You can write your **custom stress tool** (HTTP(S) Client) with Delphi (It happens to be my favorite language so I advocate it) using light HTTP(S) library such as [RTC SDK](http://www.realthinclient.com/) and [OmniThreadLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/) for multithreading.

See this [page](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/borland.public.delphi.thirdpartytools.general/2006-09/msg00668.html) for a clue/hint.

---

**Edit:**

Excerpt from Demos\Readme_Demos.txt in RealThinClient_SDK331.zip

> App Client, Server and ISAPI demos can be used to stress-test RTC
>   component  using Remote Functions with strong encryption by opening
>   hundreds of connections  from each client and flooding the
>   Server/ISAPI with requests.
>
> App Client Demo is ideal for stress-testing RTC remote functions using
>   multiple  connections in multi-threaded mode, visualy showing activity
>   and stage for each  connection in a live graph. Client can choose
>   between "Proxy" and standard connection  components, to see the
>   difference in bandwidth usage and distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard Erlang is pretty good for such applications as it is very efficient to spawn many processes in Erlang quickly. But I think using Python would be fine too, just use the popen module to spawn multiple processes. 
After all you are limited by how many you can run at the same time depending on how many processors your machine has. The choice of language may not matter as much depending on what you are doing with the data downloaded from these URLs as that may be more processing intensive than the cost of spawning.

Comment: 'After all you are limited by how many you can run at the same time depending on how many processors your machine has' - this app is likely to be I/O limited even with only a single CPU, so lots of threads can run lots of POST requests to lots of URLs concurrently.